# Entity Framework : ProviderManifestToken 2005

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005

I changed my ProviderManifestToken to 2005 because our production DB is Sql Server 2005.

After the change, I get an error:

> The Type date is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only
>   primitive types can be used without qualification.

The error is on this mapping:

```
<Property Name="LoogingDate" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Date` type doesn't exist in SQL Server 2005. You can manually change it to `DateTime` or simply regenerate your EDMX from SQL Server 2005 database (you can also use newer database server but your database must run with compatibility level set to 90).